# MySQL Help: How do I automatically update a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `cups` with the columns `item_num, product_name, amount, price, total`.

I want to automatically update `total = amount * price` when I enter a new row with just the `item_num, product_name, amount, price`.

How do I do this?

Comment: You could use a generated column

Comment: Consider whether you really need to store such easily derivable data

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generated column:

```
alter table cups add column total decimal(20, 4)
    generated always as (amount * price);
```

This calculates the `total` when the column is used, so it is always up-to-date.

Comment: Was typing this in, but you beat me to it ;) Only thing I could add is a link to formal documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, you can create a simple query that produce really up-to-date rows result contains common calculation in "total" colum which complemented by sql standard (ISO/IEC). Take a look this one..

```
select
  item_num,
  product_name,
  amount,
  price,
  (amount * price) as total
from cups
```